# Reading data from MongoDB using ExpressJS and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongojs

I'm trying to read some information from my local database and I have 2 data set in Users Collection like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a70813c638de536e0378945"),
    "name" : "salam",
    "age" : 17
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7112be5fcebe8a4abdf9b1"),
    "name" : "mostafa"
}
```

I can't gain the value of age with the following code:

```
db.Users.find({name: 'salam'}, function (err, data) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    else{
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

is there any possible way to reach it (17 I mean)?

Comment: console.log(data[0].age);

Comment: can you show your output of  console.log(data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data can be from 0 to 2 records since your DB contains 2 records.

So you can understand how this works, try this:

```
db.Users.find({name: 'salam'}, function (err, data) {
   if(err){
       console.log(err)
   }
   else{
       Array.from(data).forEach( (record) => {
         console.log(record.age);
       });
   }
});
```

You should get only 1 record.  However, in the future, when your queries return multiple records, you will know how to iterate through them.

I used the word, "record," but you can name it anything you want - users, people, etc.

Comment: `Array.from(data).forEach(record) => {
SyntaxError: Unexpected token.
`

Comment: My mistake.  I missed 2 parentheses.  I edited my answer.